# How to split datasets into specific numbers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I am using the keras MNIST dataset that comes with a training set of 60k images and a test set of 10k images. In my homework, I am being prompted to split the training set further into 50k for training and the 10k for validation. I'm a little unsure on how to do this and/or approach this, as I haven't had to split a dataset into specific numbers like that before. This is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from util import func_confusion_matrix

# load (downloaded if needed) the MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# transform each image from 28 by28 to a 784 pixel vector
pixel_count = x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2]
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], pixel_count).astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], pixel_count).astype('float32')

# normalize inputs from gray scale of 0-255 to values between 0-1
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use sklearn package:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from util import func_confusion_matrix

# load (downloaded if needed) the MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=0.1)

# here test_size=0.1 means you are selecting 10% of data for split.
```

Now you have all the data in x_train,x_test,x_val and y_train,y_test,y_val  variables.

Comment: So 10% of 60k would go into the validation set ?

Comment: Yes. You can also read the function definition from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the `mnist` comes pre-shuffled so you can just use indexing to select the last 10,000 observations of the training set as the validation set.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_val = x_train[-10000:]

x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]
```